# Linq Query for dataset in c#?

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-dataset

I have dataset which contains two tables like this:

```
DataTable dtFields = new DataTable("tmpFieldTable");

dtFields.Columns.Add("FieldID");
dtFields.Columns.Add("CDGroupID");
dtFields.Columns.Add("CDCaption");
dtFields.Columns.Add("fldIndex");

DataTable dtCDGroup = new DataTable("tmpCDGroup");

dtCDGroup.Columns.Add("CDGroupID");
dtCDGroup.Columns.Add("Name");
dtCDGroup.Columns.Add("Priority");

DataSet ds = new DataSet("tmpFieldSet");

ds.Tables.Add(dtFields);
ds.Tables.Add(dtCDGroup);
```

How can I write following SQL query to LINQ

```
queryString = "Select FieldID, tmpCDGroup.Name, CDCaption, IIF(ISNULL(Priority),99,Priority), fldIndex from tmpFieldList LEFT OUTER JOIN tmpCDGroup ON tmpFieldList.CDGroupID = tmpCDGroup.CDGroupID order by 4,5 ";
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're ordering by "4,5", but it would be like this:

```
var resultArray = tmpFieldList.Join(
    tmpCDGroup,                           // inner join collection
    fieldList => fieldList.CDGroupID,     // outer key selector
    cd => cd.CDGroupID,                   // inner key selector
    (fieldList, cd) => new {             // result selector
        FieldID = fieldList.FieldID, 
        Name = cd.Name, 
        CDCaption = cd.CDCaption, 
        Priority = fieldList.Priority ?? 99, 
        fldIndex = fieldList.fldIndex
     })
.OrderBy(result => result.Priority)
.ThenBy(result => result.fldIndex)
.ToArray();
```

Then you can access using, for example,

```
resultArray[0].FieldID
```

, etc.

Comment: As i am new LINQ, please tell me how to extract result from above quey?

Comment: @NIleshLanke I updated the answer, hope that helps.  It's just an array of the anonymous type with "FieldID", "Name", etc. properties.

Comment: @NellshLanke: Have a look at [Linq 101](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b). There are many great examples to get started with LINQ.

Comment: @dbaseman: `order by 4, 5` in SQL means ordering by the 4th and 5th column. So the order by should look like `.OrderBy(result=>result.Priority).ThenBy(result=>result.fldIndex)`.

Comment: @raznagul ah, thanks, I had never seen that syntax before.  Answer is corrected.

Comment: @dbaseman Above code throws an Exception as specified cast is not valid

Comment: @raznagul, I wonder if that's because of the part the sets Priority to default.  Can you try the above update?

Comment: If the values of Priority have different types the `OrderBy` trows an `ArgumentException`. I haven't encounter other Exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

This might work or at least help to get it working. Note that i've changed the type of some columns.

```
var result = from field in dtFields.AsEnumerable()
             join cdGroup in dtCDGroup.AsEnumerable()
             on field.Field<int>("CDGroupID") equals cdGroup.Field<int>("CDGroupID") 
                    into fieldGroup
             from row in fieldGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
             let priority = row.IsNull("Priority") ? 99 : row.Field<int>("Priority")
             orderby priority, row.Field<int>("fldIndex")
             select new
             {
                 FieldID   = row.Field<int>("FieldID"),
                 GroupName = row.Field<int>("Name"),
                 CDCaption = row.Field<int>("CDCaption"),
                 Priority  = priority,
                 fldIndex  = row.Field<int>("fldIndex")
             };
```